# PuLP python - how to formulate constraint with a binary variable

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I am working on a logistics supply-demand problem involving the loading of vessels over a 7-day horizon.

I am trying to define a binary variable that indicates the `date` a `vessel` is loaded i.e. 1 = Can load or 0 = can't load. This criteria is determined by the inventory availability: if material is available, the vessel can load.

**Current output**

Currently the output of the binary variable is always 1, which is incorrect because once the vessel is loaded then the shipment is complete. As a result the shipment variable (which signifies what date the vessel demand is satisfied) is at 1.0 for each day in the planned horizon

**Desired Output**

I need the binary variable to signify when a vessel can load (1/0). The vessel can only load after it has arrived, and if sufficient material is available in the inventory.

[image: Binary Constraint Formulation]

**Code and definitions below:**

Owing to the amount of code in the model (including variable formation) it is very difficult to provide an MRE, so I am hoping that someone can spot the error in the definition of the binary variable/constraint expression.

- `vessel_grade_demand_tonnes[vessel, grade]`: Constant. the required amount, in tonnes
  of each grade required by each vessel.
- `vessel_sales_demand_vars[(vessel, grade, date)]`: Variable. The date
  a vessels demand requirements are fully satisfied i.e. ship is loaded with all grades it requires.
- `vessel_load_start_date[vessel, date]`: Binary. The date indicating
  when a vessel can be loaded. NOTE a vessel can only load if the total
  amount it requires is available in the port inventory,
  port_inventory_vars[date, grade].

Code:

```
# Vessel can only load when sufficient material available.
for date, vessel, grade in vessel_sales_temp:
  model += vessel_load_start_date[vessel, date] * vessel_sales_demand_tonnes[date, vessel, grade] <= port_inventory_vars[date, grade]

  
# All vessel requirements must be satisfied on one day, defined by loading date
for grade in grades:
  for vessel, date in vessel_load_start_date:
    model += vessel_load_start_date[vessel, date] * vessel_grade_demand_tonnes[vessel, grade] == pulp.lpSum(vessel_grade_demand_tonnes[vessel, grade])
    model += vessel_sales_demand_vars[(vessel, grade, date)] <= vessel_load_start_date[vessel, date] * vessel_grade_demand_tonnes[vessel, grade]
    
# Vessel sales requirements vars must equal the total required sales tonnes 
for vessel, grade, date in vessel_sales_demand_vars:
    model += pulp.lpSum(vessel_sales_demand_vars[vessel, grade, date]) == vessel_grade_demand_tonnes[vessel, grade]
```

All help gratefully received.

Comment: If the constraint you've shown in the formualation is the only constraint involving `y_it` then the problem is that you haven't set the constraints to control when `y_it` can be 1 - i.e. it has to be after the vessel has arrived etc.

Comment: Yes - this is the constraint I think is currently causing the issue. I have tried to define it here `# Vessel can only load when sufficient material available.
for date, vessel, grade in vessel_sales_temp:
  model += vessel_load_start_date[vessel, date] * vessel_sales_demand_tonnes[date, vessel, grade] <= port_inventory_vars[date, grade]`. The binary variable, `y_it` is supposed to be `1` when `sum(I_jt) >= sum(x_ijt)`, where `I` is the port inventory, meaning the vessel is able to load because material is available in the inventory to do so.

Comment: I should note that `load_start_date` is a dict of vessel:date combinations after the vessel has arrived.

Comment: @kabdulla could you please show how you would define the binary variable?

Comment: @cmp did you find any solution for this?